# How to make sure random key generated in trigger complies to unique constraint

Tags: oracle, random, plsql, unique

Happy new year! :)

I have a table and upon insert I fill the column `random_key` with a random string using a trigger.
This column has a unique constraint, but theoretically it is possible that the random string the trigger generates is not unique, and the record will not be inserted.

Is there a way to avoid this in the trigger? Or do I have to create an insert procedure?

**edit:** (copied from comments and elaborated)

I have a normal id in this table, but for external use (the internet) I require a completely random id, so that the id of the next row in the table cannot be guessed.

Salting with the id + constant might work. I'll think it over.

Judging by the answers so far it appears there is no simple solution to avoid duplication in the trigger. That is an answer too. :)

Comment: would it hurt your random key to be salted with an incrementing number/sequence in addition to the random text?

Comment: What's the point in having a random string in a column? If you need a surrogate key what's wrong with a sequence?

Comment: Use sequence. If you have filled with some data already, just find maximal unique value and start your sequence from their.

Comment: Uniqueness pretty much rules out random.  Attempting to ban duplicates is to impose an order.

Comment: I have a normal id in this table, but for external use (the internet) I require a completely random id. Salting with the id might work. I'll think it over.

Comment: Sys_guid is globally unique. I.e. Is safe when multiple databases Are involved

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [SYS_GUID](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions168.htm) function. this will return a unique string.

```
SQL> select sys_guid() from dual;

SYS_GUID()
--------------------------------
D24FC8257402951BE0401AA2C9997E18
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I need and have a more complex unique identifier.

Comment: @BazzPsychoNut - you need to tell us more about your requirements, because as it stands at the moment you have a nonsensical specification.

Comment: Tell you exact specification so that we could answer your problem